# show image on slides

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have put four images on slide and I display them one by one using the pause command. I want to display row-wise, but they are getting displayed vertically one by one.

Below is my code:

```
      \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}[t]
      \column{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc5.jpg}\\
     \pause% 
      &\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc6.jpg}\\[-1.5mm]\pause%
     \column{.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc8.jpg}\\
     \pause%
     &\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc7.jpg}
     \end{columns}
     \end{frame}
```

I want to display images in following order: pc5,pc6,pc7,pc8
but my code displays it as pc5,pc7,pc6,pc8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get finer control over the overlay specification, instead of `\pause` you can use `\onslide`:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\onslide<1->{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc5.jpg}\\}
\onslide<3->{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc7.jpg}}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\onslide<2->{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc6.jpg}\\}
\onslide<4->{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc8.jpg}}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Another option is to use the fact that `\includegraphics` is overlay-aware and say something like:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<1->[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc5.jpg}\\
\includegraphics<3->[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc7.jpg}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<2->[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc6.jpg}\\
\includegraphics<4->[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{pc8.jpg}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The first image however might appear not in its final position in the first slide using this last approach. I removed the spurious `&` characters from the original code.

Comment: Thanks. but i want pc5 and pc6 on the same row

and pc8 and pc7 on another row

Comment: @Nyfer see my updated answer.